# How can i mock Server.HtmlEncode - returns null reference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, testing, moq

I'm trying to mock Server.HtmlEncode(), but I keep having a null reference exception.
I'm pretty new to the Moq framework, here is my code:

```
var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

server.Setup(svr => svr.HtmlEncode(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string s) => s);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
```

I've also tried the following:

```
context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server.HtmlEncode(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string s) => s);
```

I've found a solution but it seems an outdated [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103228/how-can-i-mock-server-htmlencode) as expect is replaced with setup.

Thanks in advance,
Arne

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the static [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode.aspx) method which works just fine and you won't need to mock it.

Another important remark: controllers have nothing to do with HTML encoding. This is the view's responsibility so you are probably approaching this from the wrong angle.

Comment: I've thought so, how you suggest I would change it then?
I need to encode to change the \r\n into <br /> and other characters so it can be placed in DB. And decode it back into the text area.
So the same view needs to do both depending on get/post.

Comment: Place it as is in the DB. When rendering make sure to HTML encode in the view or use an HTML helper which will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually found a solution.

```
var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>(MockBehavior.Strict);
server.Setup(ctx => ctx.HtmlEncode(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string s) => s);
server.Setup(ctx => ctx.HtmlDecode(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns((string s) => s);
```